# Covertir DateTime a Varchar en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día a todos, tengo una consulta en SQL Server donde tengo que seleccionar registros dependiendo de una fecha(por mes), no de un rango de fechas, para esto lo que hago es hacer un convert a los campos de fecha, pero mi consulta no me regresa resultados.

la consulta que estoy probando es la siguiente:

```
declare @Fecha datetime
set @Fecha = '2021-06-07'

select convert(varchar(20),FechaAlta, 23) from conCuentasConcentradoras
select convert(varchar(20),FechaAlta, 23) from conCuentasConcentradoras where FechaAlta = convert(varchar(20),@Fecha, 23)
select convert(varchar(20), @Fecha, 23)
```

los resultados que me arroja son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no entiendo porque en la consulta donde hago el where no regresa resultados.
Alguien que me diga que estoy haciendo mal por favor, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: que quieres decir con "donde tengo que seleccionar registros dependiendo de una fecha(por mes)", que cosa es "por mes"

Comment: Hola Japv , ok creo que está mal explicado, no es por mes lo que hacen las consultas que puse, pero igual es por un día específico del mes por ejemplo el resultado del primer select me arroja registros con fecha del 2021-07-06, pero cuando hago la comparación contra la @Fecha que estoy declarando con el mismo valor de 2021-07-06 no arroja resultados

Comment: No conviertas a varchar, compara directo FechaAlta = @Fecha

Comment: ya intenté con esta consulta `select FechaAlta from conCuentasConcentradoras where FechaAlta = @Fecha` pero sigue igual

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres convertir fechas en cadenas de caracteres? Las fechas siempre deben de ser fechas, excepto cuando se muestran. Por otro lado, si tu columna es datetime, podría tener valores de tiempo y eso evita que sea igual a una fecha sin tiempo. Es imposible saber el problema si ocultas como está la información original.

Comment: Hola Luis Cazares, el formato original de la columna es DateTime, al hacer un select a esa columna obtienes: ` 2021-06-30 12:34:57.820
2021-06-30 13:30:57.130
2021-07-04 23:29:01.637
2021-07-05 10:56:22.990
2021-07-05 11:08:18.017
2021-07-05 13:59:17.397
2021-07-06 13:31:45.200
2021-07-06 13:46:22.250` como resultado lo convierto a cadena de caracteres porque solo me interesa comparar el año, el mes y el día sin importar las horas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicación en la consulta:

```
declare @Fecha datetime
set @Fecha = '2021-06-07'

select * from 
conCuentasConcentradoras
-- La conversión se hace en el where de la consulta y se hace para obtener
-- solo la parte de la fecha sin la hora para que la búsqueda coincida
-- si FechaAlta es igual '2021-06-07 10:10:10' entonces no sería igual a '2021-06-07'
-- pero extrayendo solo la fecha con convert() entonces sí se pueden comparar
where CONVERT(date,FechaAlta) = @fecha
```

Comment: muchas gracias Lobos, pero me arroja este error `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 8
'DATE' no es un nombre de función integrada reconocido.
`

Comment: Cierto, ya lo corregí.

Comment: muchas gracias Lobos